# Is Ephesians 2:17 an allusion to Isaiah 57:19?

Tags: isaiah, paul, ephesians, intertextuality

Ephesians 2:17 ESV

> 17 ***And he came and preached peace to you who were far off and peace to those who were near***.

Isaiah 57:19 ESV

> creating the fruit of the lips.
> Peace, ***peace, to the far and to the near,” says the Lord***,
> “and I will heal him.

Is there an allusion in the above passage?

Answer (score 2):

Is Ephesians 2:17 an allusion to Isaiah 57:19?

Yes, Isaiah is famous for his Messianic connections. This is another one.

ESV Isaiah 57:

> 19 creating the fruit of the lips. **Peace**[1],  **peace**[2], to the **far** and to the **near**,” says the Lord, “and I will heal him.

Ephesians 2:

> 17 And he came and preached **peace**[1] to you who were **far** off and **peace**[2] to those who were **near**.

Ellicott makes this connection:

> To you which were afar off, and to them that were nigh.—As the enmity was the enmity with God, so the peace is **peace with God**; but still the Apostle, having the idea of reunion between Jew and Gentile present to his mind, cannot refrain from bringing out clearly the call of both to one peace, and therefore to unity with one another. The passage is a quotation from Isaiah 57:19.

Jesus was born to give the Jews and Gentiles peace,
Luke 2:

> 14 “Glory to God in the highest heaven,
> and on earth **peace** to those on whom his favor rests.”